# Zoom, Extend dimensions of Cavans in Android

Tags: android, canvas

I do not know how to explain my problem.
I have a View of figures created with canvas, and I want to zoom and extend the canvas if one of the figures is taken to the edge of the canvas.
I'll leave some images to express myself better.

[If I add a new figure, it expands the canvas (color light blue) and I can move the canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0SXD.png)

[and I zoom the canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWDwp.png)

Answer (score 0):

You will run quickly out of memory witch such architecture (having huge canvas and viewing just part of it).

Rather keep geometry elements in some list, with positions/sizes, then have "camera-view" matrix which will be used to calculate actual coordinates of each element (such matrix will allow you to do all kind of viewport actions, moving it around, scaling, rotating, even some skewing for fun).

Have a canvas which is only on screen, and only 1:1 of pixel size, i.e. as target viewport surface to be drawn at. Then each shape, which after transformation fits into that area, draw over the canvas, in proper scale.

That way, if your elements are using vectorized shapes, will stay sharp and crisp even at high levels of zoom, while the full canvas would already be beyond memory limits in such case.

But doing this you may run into different kind of problem, with performance. Redrawing the canvas each time from scratch, with big amount of elements, may take considerable time. Several techniques exists to improve that, I don't believe you will ever have thousands of elements, so culling out all elements should be ok. But various caches, including re-using several canvas to "tile" the final area, to improve moving around speed, may be implemented.

But for a start, you can just simply redraw the canvas with transformed geometry, the `Paint` itself will already cut out the elements which are outside of area after transformation. After you have this basic solution (and you did write the code, which will translate touch gestures into view matrix modifications, instead of scrolling the layout), you can experiment with performance, maybe the simple way will be already sufficient for your needs, without any tiling/caching.

Maybe check how 3D engines work, they don't have huge canvas, but they draw only the visible area at screen, and they transform the geometry first in the point coordinates form, not in rendered pixels. The principle can be applied also for 2D (it's the same thing, just without 6DOF rotations and linear perspective).